# MVC 5 Linq-SQL Performing search from 3 joined Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

[image: MVC MODEL]

Using this model, I would like to perform a left outer join of the course table to the student table and display them with a search dropdown menu on the courses.
My MVC code is :

```
  var query = from c in db.Students
                    join o in db.Enrollments on c.StudentID equals o.StudentID 
                    join co in db.Courses on o.CourseID equals co.CourseID into sr
                    from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new Student
                    {
                         FirstName=c.FirstName,
                         LastName=c.LastName,
                         EnrollmentDate=c.EnrollmentDate,
                         MiddleName=c.MiddleName,
                         StudentID=c.StudentID
                        //StudentName = c.FirstName.ToString(),
                        //CourseID = x.CourseID.ToString(),
                        //CourseName = x.Title.ToString()
                        //== null ? -1 : x.Title
                    };   
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(course))
        {
         students = query.Where(x => x.CourseName == course).Select(item=>new Student(){FirstName = c.FirstName.ToString()}).ToList();
        }
        return View(students);
```

But I can't get it to work. Can someone please enlighten me on how to correctly do this.
This is the sample screen : 
[image]

Comment: Please, clarify what *I can't get it to work* means. Exception? Wrong results? And what you are using Linq to Sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: error is : The name 'c' does not exist in the current context upon the students = query.Where(x => x.CourseName == course).Select(item=>new Student(){FirstName = c.FirstName.ToString()}).ToList(); Fist of all, am I doing this correctly? another error is , Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You have `item` variable name in your select operator. Correct query looks like `students = query.Where(x => x.CourseName == course).Select(item => new Student {FirstName = item.FirstName}).ToList();` If that's it, then you can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public List<Student> GetStudentsByCourseName(string courseName)
    {
        var list = new List<Student>();
        var course = db.Courses.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Title == courseName);

        if (course != null)
        {
            list = course.Enrollments.Select(o => new Student {
                    FirstName = o.Student.FirstName,
                    LastName = o.Student.LastName
                }).ToList();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Ronald, Thank You for this, However, I'd like to ask what If id like both courses and student firstname to be the search queries?

Comment: You could further refine the result like this, GetStudentsByCourseName("biology").Where(student => student.FirstName == "bob")

Comment: Thanks Man, Your an angel :D Im new to asp.net mvc, and I already love this language :D